# Topbar in Foundation js not working on small screens in an asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, zurb-foundation

I cannot get the topbar to work on small screens (www.mco.ntx-designs.com is where you can see).  When you press the menu icon, nothing happens.  I know that JQuery is loading and I mut presume that the foundation.topbar.js is loading as well but I have racked my brain and cannot figure this out.  Here's my code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MCO.Master.cs" Inherits="mco.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/mco.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Styles/foundation.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Styles/foundation.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/vendor/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

        alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

    } else {

        alert("jQuery library is not found!");

    }
</script>-->
    <form runat="server">
    <script src="~/Scripts/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/foundation/foundation.topbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <Header class="row" id="masterpageHeader">
      <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12" id="logoTop">
      <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/mcoLogo.png" runat="server" AlternateText="Melissa Community Outreach Logo" />
      </div>
       <div class="sticky large-12 medium-12 small-12">
       <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="sticky_on: large">
        <ul class="title-area">
         <li class="name">
         <h1><a href="#">Melissa Community Outreach</a></h1>
         </li>
         <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href=""><span>Menu</span></a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      <section class="top-bar-section">
      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
       <ul class="right">
       <li runat="server" id="mainHomeLink" class=""><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink13" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/">Home</asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="mainGivingLink" class=""><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/giving/">Giving</asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="mainVolunteeringLink" class=""><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/volunteering/">Volunteering</asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="mainHoursLink" class=""><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/hours/">Hours</asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="mainLocationLink" class=""><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/location/">Location</asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="mainAboutLink" class="has-dropdown">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink10" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/about/">About</asp:HyperLink>
         <ul class="dropdown">
         <li  class="active"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink11" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/mission-statement/">Mission Statement</asp:HyperLink>
         </li>
         <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink12" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/directors/">Directors</asp:HyperLink>
         </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
         <li>
         <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </section>
      </nav>
      </div>
     </Header>
        <main class="row">
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        </main>
    <footer class="row" id="footerMain">
     <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12" id="newsletterFooter">
      <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 left column">
      <span class="largerText2">Stay up to date with what's happening with Melissa Community Outreach</span><br />
      <span class="smallerText">Sign up to receive monthly emails with our latest information:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 right"><asp:TextBox ID="emailSignupMain" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="53px" CssClass="textBoxWhite left" ></asp:TextBox><span class="button left">Email</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;<br /></div>
      </div>
     <div class="large-12" id="linksFooter1">
     <div class="large-5 medium-5 small-12 borderRightSmall text-center columns"><span class="text-center" id="aboutFooterHead">Melissa Community Outreach</span><br /><br />
     We are a non-profit organization that helps out needy families in Melissa, Texas.&nbsp;&nbsp;We provide food, clothing and other necessary items
     for people who cannot afford to pay for these items themselves.&nbsp;&nbsp;If you or someone you know needs help please <asp:HyperLink ID="contactUs1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/contact">contact us</asp:HyperLink>
     information about what services we offer.
     </div>
     <div class="large-7 medium-7 small-12 columns">
     <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 borderRightSmall text-center columns"><span class="largerText">Important Links</span><br /><asp:HyperLink ID="feedingamerica" NavigateUrl="http://www.feedingamerica.org/" Target="_blank" runat="server">www.feedingamerica.org</asp:HyperLink>
     <br />
     <asp:HyperLink ID="theSamaritansInn" NavigateUrl="http://www.thesamaritansinn.org" Target="_blank" runat="server">The Samaritan's Inn</asp:HyperLink>
     <br /><br /><br /></div>
     <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 borderRightSmall text-center columns"><span class="largerText">More Text</span><br />More text can go into this spot.<br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
     <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 text-center columns"><span class="largerText">More Text 2</span><br />More text can go into this spot.<br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12" id="footerRed">
     <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 left column">
     <span class="smallerText">Copyright © 2012 <strong><asp:HyperLink ID="ntxDesigns" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.ntx-designs.com" Target="_blank">NTX Designs</asp:HyperLink></strong>. All right reserved.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <span class="largerText"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/giving/">Giving</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/volunteering/">Volunteering</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/hours/">Hours</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/location/">Location</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/about/">About</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     </div>
     <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 text-right right column">
     <asp:Image ID="googleIcon" ImageUrl="~/images/social-049_google.png" runat="server" AlternateText="Google Social Media Icon" />
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/images/social-043_twitter.png" runat="server" AlternateText="Twitter Social Media Icon" />
     <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="~/images/social-046_facebook.png" runat="server" AlternateText="Facebook Social Media Icon" />
     </div>
     </div>
    </footer>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you notice that your scripts are not loaded, they are incorrect prefixed with a ~. 

GET http://www.mco.ntx-designs.com/~/Scripts/foundation/foundation.topbar.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Yep!  Added a runt="server" and everything works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yep! Added a runt="server" and everything works perfectly. Thanks!